# TSQL - New column value based on other columns with highest level of match

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I've got a mapping table with the following information:

```
Number      | FCODE     |  CCODE
---------------------------------------------

0*********  |   12345   |   1

01********  |   12345   |   2

012*******  |   *****   |   3

012*******  |   12345   |   4

0454******  |   12345   |   5

0123******  |   12345   |   6
```

And another fact table with the following info:

```
Number     | FCODE
-------------------------------
0123456789 | 12345
0123456789 | 545243
0129456789 | 545243
0129456789 | 12345
```

Ideally I should add CCode in the fact table with the highest matching value of Number (first) & FCODE (second)

So for example the first record: Number: 0123456789 FCode: 12345 should result to have value CCode 6 to be added in the fact table

If number is 0129456789 & FCode 12345, CCode should become 4.

I tried working with a RANK function, but I'm missing something but cannot see what

Here is the SQL query I have, but does not do what I expected..

```
SELECT ltd.Number, ltd.FCode, td.CCode
FROM dbo.Test_Fact ltd LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *, MYRANK = RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Number DESC)
    FROM dbo.Test_Mapping) td
    ON SUBSTRING(ltd.Number, 1, LEN(LEFT(td.Number, charindex('*', td.Number)-1))) = LEFT(td.Number, charindex('*', td.Number)-1)
ORDER BY td.MYRANK
```

Any support is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What a `CCode` value should be for `0123456789 | 545243` and `0129456789 | 545243` in result? `NULL`s or `3`? Add a desired result.

Comment: Good question, which I forgot to add in the original post. Indeed it should be null if one of both is not matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use values from the `mapping` table as regular expression patterns to match against values in a `fact` table.

And if i understand correctly, you need to get maximum `CCODE` for both matches `mapping.Number` with `fact.Number` and `mapping.FCode` with `fact.FCode`.

If so, you can select `TOP 1` of matching rows from `mapping` table sorted by `CCODE` in descending order.

To get a final result you can use `OUTER APPLY` like this

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        ccode, 
        (replace(Number, '*', '') + '%') as number_pattern,
        (replace(fcode, '*', '') + '%') as fcode_pattern
    FROM mappings
)
SELECT
    f.Number,
    f.FCode,
    m.CCode
FROM 
    fact f 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM CTE m
    WHERE f.Number LIKE m.number_pattern 
          AND f.fcode LIKE m.fcode_pattern
    ORDER BY m.ccode DESC
) m
```

Please, check a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3587b848b19b12c2a21b14bcaf9a6aba).

Result:

```
Number     | FCode  | CCode
:--------- | :----- | ----:
0123456789 | 12345  |     6
0123456789 | 545243 |     3
0129456789 | 545243 |     3
0129456789 | 12345  |     4
```

As per @HABO comment, to retain pattern's length and symbol order, it's more correct to use an underscore to replace an asterisk in the pattern. And then query would be like this

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        ccode, 
        replace(Number, '*', '_') as number_pattern,
        replace(fcode, '*', '_') as fcode_pattern
    FROM mappings
)
SELECT
    f.Number,
    f.FCode,
    m.CCode
FROM 
    fact f 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM CTE m
    WHERE f.Number LIKE m.number_pattern 
          AND f.fcode LIKE m.fcode_pattern
    ORDER BY m.ccode DESC
) m
```

Working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6f6bdc62acee632aaaa322048ae16d9).

This query produces `NULL` as `CCode` for second and third rows in `fact` table, because there is no any match in the `mappings` table.

```
Number     | FCode  | CCode
:--------- | :----- | ----:
0123456789 | 12345  |     6
0123456789 | 545243 |  null
0129456789 | 545243 |  null
0129456789 | 12345  |     4
```

Comment: It might be more appropriate to replace `*` in the pattern with [`_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-match-one-character-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to match the specified arrangement and number of characters. Removing all of the `*` characters from _anywhere_ in the pattern and then appending a `%` may be more of a semantic change than the OP wants. For example, it would change `*1*3*5*7*9` into `13579%` aka _starting with_ `13579`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but in my case this is not needed. Those things won't happen. :)

Comment: @Alexey, this is great thanks a lot. It seems I was far off and wouldn't get it.